# Why aren't all the background threads suspended when background time expires?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have some background threads in my app where I have some `NSTimer`s running in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` mode. When I press home button the app goes to background.

If I don't call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` the threads get suspended when the application is in background. But if I call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` the threads **don't get suspended even after the expiration handler returns**.

Why is it that background threads keep running in one case while in another case they don't? When will the background threads get suspended in the second case?

Comment: Did you use a simulator?

Comment: Are you doing this while running the app from Xcode? That alters the background running behavior. Make sure you run the app by clicking on the app’s icon on your device screen, not running it from Xcode.

Comment: Yes I am running it in simulator.  I thought I just have to call `endBackgroundTask:` in expiration handler. After adding this call in `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`, the background threads are getting suspended as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this document [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpiratio)

> This method lets your app continue to run for a period of time after it transitions to the background.

That why if you call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` the threads don't get suspended.

And

> Each call to this method must be balanced by a matching call to the **endBackgroundTask:** method. Apps running background tasks have a finite amount of time in which to run them. (You can find out how much time is available using the backgroundTimeRemaining property.) If you do not call endBackgroundTask: for each task before time expires, the system kills the app. If you provide a block object in the handler parameter, the system calls your handler before time expires to give you a chance to end the task.

So the background threads get suspended in the second case when you use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` right way with `endBackgroundTask:` by adding `endBackgroundTask:` outside of expiration handler.

Comment: The background threads don't get suspended in the second case even after the expiration handler returns. I am having trouble understanding why this should be the case.

Comment: You should add `endBackgroundTask:` after the expiration handler ends.

Comment: I thought I just have to add it in expiration handler. After adding this call to `endBackgroundTask:` outside of expiration handler it is working as expected.

Comment: Yes, it's what i mean ;). Congratulation.

Comment: @trungdc In the second case I said the background threads get suspended. If you edit your answer and include what we discussed in the comments I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: Editted. You can check again :). If it's not ok enough, tell me.